# Android - How to get ListView item at absolute position?

Tags: java, android

So ListView Adapter has the getView method and it's called everytime the display of the listview is changed... so the 0th element becomes the 1st element in the viewport. I think...

How do i basically access the 0TH element in the Listview? Not the 1st element in the viewport? First element in the entire ListView? I want tot access elements by an absolute index so it doesn't matter which one is visible, i want to access them based on their index in the ListView.

How do i do this?

Comment: onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) does exactly what you ask for. The position argument is the actual position in the list, and not the position of the elements on the screen.

Comment: I want to change the item's background color. I don't want that to happen on click. I want it to happen when the list is populated. Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to create a custom adapter to do that. Look up Listview custom adapter. There are lots of tutorials on this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access any `View` in the `ListView` by index, because it's recycling them and essentially there are no views other than you see plus some cache.

And actually you shouldn't want to do this. If you want to manipulate with the `ListView`'s data, change the underlying collection via `Adapter`, so in overriden `getView()` of your adapter you can decide how to render the particular view (what background color to set in your case).

So you'll have something like this:

```
private class Item {
     Color getBgColor {...}
}

private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter { // or WhateverAdapter you have
    Item getItem(int id) {...}

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(getItem(position).getBgColor());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, how do i change an item's background color via the adapter?

Comment: I really don't want to spam this question , can i contact you in some other way?